# Calling a JavaScript function within an InfoWindow (Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm having an issue calling a javascript function within a Google Maps InfoWindow. The relevant code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
/* … unnecessary code */

function closeTo(url_slug) {
    parent.url_slug = url_slug;
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
}

var contentString = '<a href="javascript:closeTo(\'foo\');">close</a>';

var callout = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:contentString
});

//-->
</script>
```

The above example results in a blank map. However, if I change the content string to this:

```
var contentString = '<a href="#">close</a>';
```

It works just fine. Also, I've called the function from a link on the page (not an InfoWindow) and it works as well. The general idea is to respond to a click in an InfoWindow, close the fancybox, and redirect to the location provided. So, my question is this. How do I call a function within an InfoWindow?

Comment: Blank map? On load or after you click 'close'?

Comment: Anything in your browser's JavaScript console when this problem arises? Can you point to a link where we can see this behavior?  If all else fails, maybe try putting the JavaScript in an onclick (and follow it the call with closeTo() with `;return false;`) and see if that does the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [nothing inherently wrong](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo34) with calling a javascript function from an infoWindow. I suggest you check the JavaScript error log and try and track down what is happening once *closeTo* is called.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was passing the information via PHP, failed to addslashes to the javascript string.

Comment: @sdover102 No problem :) Glad you sorted it out.